# How to run a script after another without being able to call it in the first script?

Tags: linux, bash

My problem is, that I have a first script, which starts some emulation. When I run this, the emulation starts (in the console) and you need to input the password.

Piping in the password doesn't work. Is there a way to input the password in any way and then run the second script?

The solution I am searching for is something like that the first script checks the output in the console and after the password prompt, react, put in the password and start the new script.

I hope my problem is understandably described.

Comment: Can you explain with a proper script & its statements?

Comment: I will just use a qemu command and then I want to continue..

Comment: maybe you should try expect? it can help you input the password

Comment: great! That is something I searched for. I will try it out

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.